# Is it possible to store view code in files?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

Right now I enter view code (map & reduce) in the couchbase UI. This is very inconvenient, and I was wondering if there is a way to make couchbase scan the code from a folder?

This will allow me to put this code under version control, and allow me to create a script that copies code between environments.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of a 'native' way to store views in files, but you can add and remove views via REST. So you could implement a workaround.

[Views REST API](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/REST/rest-views-intro.html)